# How to override inherited secrets in GitHub reusable actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have workflows A and B that both call workflow C. There are many secrets that are set up in git repository. Workflow C uses 100 secrets. I need to pass 99 of them the same way from workflows A and B. But one of them are different. Can I make workflow C inherit all the secrets an override only one of them?
Something like:
**A:**

```
name: Reusable workflow
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
    ...
env:
  SECRET_1: ${{ secrets.SECRET_1 }}
  SECRET_2: ${{ secrets.SECRET_2 }}
  ...
  SECRET_100: ${{ secrets.SECRET_100 }}
jobs:
   ...
```

**A:**

```
name: Workflow A
on: ["workflow_dispatch"]

jobs:
  C:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/C.yaml
  secrets: 
    - inherit
    - SECRET_100: ${{ secrets.SECRET_100_FOR_A }}
jobs:
   ...
```

**B:**

```
name: Workflow B
on: ["workflow_dispatch"]

jobs:
  C:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/C.yaml
  secrets: 
    - inherit
    - SECRET_100: ${{ secrets.SECRET_100_FOR_B }}
jobs:
   ...
```

I've tried reading documentation and googling and also tried to pass every secret explicitly without `inherit` keyword - but it is not very scalable.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't. A workaround could be to always update the secret value before calling the reusable, using a third secret variable that would be used in the reusable workflow, and updated according to workflow A or workflow B. An option to do so is to use [an action to create/update secrets](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/create-github-secret-action).

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but maybe it will help someone. This assumes that the secret value is set statically in the repo and not dynamically generated.

You can pass in the *name* of the secret as an input to the reusable workflow, and then access that secret using the `secrets` context and the secret name in brackets `[]` - `${{ secrets[inputs.secret-name-input] }}`. This also keeps the secret safe since you're only passing in the name of it.

So in your case, the workflows would be updated like this:

**C:**

```
name: Reusable workflow
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      secret-100-name:
        type: string

env:
  SECRET_1: ${{ secrets.SECRET_1 }}
  SECRET_2: ${{ secrets.SECRET_2 }}
  ...
  SECRET_100: ${{ secrets[inputs.secret-100-name] }}
jobs:
   ...
```

**A:**

```
name: Workflow A
on: ["workflow_dispatch"]

jobs:
  C:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/C.yaml
    with:
      secret-100-name: SECRET_100_FOR_A # DEFINE A SECRET IN THIS REPO NAMED `SECRET_100_FOR_A`
    secrets: inherit
    
jobs:
   ...
```

**B:**

```
name: Workflow B
on: ["workflow_dispatch"]

jobs:
  C:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/C.yaml
    with:
      secret-100-name: SECRET_100_FOR_B # DEFINE A SECRET IN THIS REPO NAMED `SECRET_100_FOR_B`
    secrets: inherit

jobs:
   ...
```